# How to index each node in O(1) complexity and update all indexes each time when doing insertion/deletion/rotations in a Balanced AVL tree

Tags: python, recursion, avl-tree

The solution I have now is something of an in order traversal:

```
def update_index(self, current: AVLTreeNode) -> None:
    """
    Call updated_index_aux to traverse the tree in order and update the index appropriately
    """
    # if current is not None:
    #     return current.index
    # return 0
    self.index = 0
    self.update_index_aux(current)

def update_index_aux(self, current: AVLTreeNode) -> None:

    if current is not None: #Base case if current is None
        self.update_index_aux(current.left)
        current.index = self.index
        self.index += 1
        self.update_index_aux(current.right)
```

but this requires me to call this method each time i insert/delete which is not efficient, how do i make it O(1) such that everything is updated each time i insert/delete or perform a rotation. It seems similar to get_height() method in an AVL tree which is O(1) so this is called on insert and delete:

```
# Update height of current node
current.height = max(self.get_height(current.left),
                     self.get_height(current.right)) + 1
```

but im not sure how to take these solutions to make it O(1) so i dont have to traverse the tree each time i insert or delete.

my get_height function:

```
def get_height(self, current: AVLTreeNode) -> int:
        if current is not None:
            return current.height
        return 0
```

Below is my insert function into a AVL tree for reference:

```
def insert_aux(self, current: AVLTreeNode, key: K, item: I) -> AVLTreeNode:
        """
            Attempts to insert an item into the tree, it uses the Key to insert it
        """
        if current is None:  # base case: at the leaf
            current = AVLTreeNode(key, item)
            self.length += 1
        elif key < current.key:
            current.left = self.insert_aux(current.left, key, item)
        elif key > current.key:
            current.right = self.insert_aux(current.right, key, item)
        else:  # key == current.key
            raise ValueError('Inserting duplicate item')
        current.height = max(self.get_height(current.left), self.get_height(current.right)) + 1 #Update height of current node  
        current = self.rebalance(current) #Rebalance tree after insertion if needed
        
        
        return current
```

The reason i need to index each node is because I need to code a function that finds and gets a range of items stored in the AVL tree based on a range of indexes. I did that part already but I can only do it when the nodes are already indexed and the only way i can think of to index the nodes is in order traversal to each node and updating the index accordingly but I cant do it this way so Im trying to think of a way to update each index during insertion/deletion/rotations without needing to traverse each node and update

Comment: Your `get_height` function is not O(1).

Comment: Your goal is to update the index of each node. Can you introduce a method to access each node without traversing?

Comment: i edited the post to add my get_height function

Comment: not sure how to access each node without traversing, Ive been at this for days and i cant think of a solution

Comment: I added more information to my post